# HLSL fixed lighting location

Tags: hlsl, direction, light

Hi im trying to create a shader for my 3D models with materials and fog. Everything works fine but the light direction. I'm not sure what to set it to so I used a fixed value, but when I rotate my 3D model (which is a simple textured sphere) the light rotates with it. I want to change my code so that my light stays in one place according to the camera and not the object itself. I have tried multiplying the view matrix by the input normals but the same result occurs.

Also, should I be setting the light direction according to the camera instead?

EDIT: removed pastebin link since that is against the rules...

Comment: Please don't post links to code.

Comment: how should I show the code? wouldn't it be too big to post here?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you can't do that then this may not be the best forum for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use camera depended values just for transforming vertex pos to view and projected position (needed in shaders for clipping and rasterizer stage). The video cards needs to know, where to draw your pixel.

For lighting you normally pass additional to the camera transformed value the world position of the vertex and the normal in world position to the needed shader stages (i.e pixel shader stage for phong lighting).

So you can set your light position, or better light direction in world space coordinate system as global variable to your shaders. With that the lighting is independent of the camera view position.

If you want to have a effect like using a flashlight. You can set the lightposition to camera position, and light direction to your look direction. So the bright parts are always in the center of your viewing frustum.

good luck